# Invalid 'in' operand a

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am getting error from javascript

> "[object Object]" TypeError: invalid 'in'
>   operand a

when I try to do ajax like

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li class='submitmore' ></li>" )
      .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
      .append('<p class="searchdata" onClick="asd(\'' + item + '\')">'+item.value+'<div class="clear"></div>')

};

function asd(itemnew){

        console.log(itemnew);

        $.each(itemnew, function (key, value) {
              console.log("item : "+ key + " value : " + value);
        });

}
```

Comment: You need to include line 1581 (and some of the surrounding code). What you've posted doesn't use `in` at all.

Comment: Where is the closing `</p>`?

Comment: Your error is a PHP error. Not Javascript or AJAX. I would recommend you change your tags and the direction of your question. As @ssube pointed out, you should include that code as well.

Comment: 'in' is inside jquery library. The error is related to $.each(itemnew,function (key,value) because it goes away when I hide it.

Comment: I am trying to print the object 'itemnew' keys and values so that I can use them further.

Comment: What is the value of `itemnew`?

Comment: `itemnew` is a string. Why are you doing `$.each(itemnew, ...)`?

Comment: Your code in the `_renderItem` function doesn't make sense. When you do `onClick="asd(\'' + item + '\')" `, you're treating item as a string. But when you do `item.value`, it must be an object. Which is it?

Comment: It's apparently an object. When you concatenate it into the `onclick` attribute, the object is converted to the string `"[object Object]"`. Then you pass this string to `asd`, which tries to loop over it with `$.each`.

Comment: How do I output this object in keys and values ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li class='submitmore' ></li>" )
      .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
      .append('<p class="searchdata">'+item.value+'<div class="clear"></div>');
};

$(document).on("p.searchdata").click(function() {
    asd($(this).closest("li.submitmore").data("item.autocomplete"));
}
```

Instead of trying to put the item into the `onclick` attribute, this allows the click handler to get it from the `.data()` that you stored.

Comment: I kind of get the logic you are trying to get it working.. but I got undefined in the console log.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with more complete code so I can see it in action?